# How should I send packets to multiple clients on UDP?

Tags: networking, socket

I'm developing a 2D action side-scroller shoot-em-up game and I recently implemented the multiplayer aspect.

When the server sends packets containing the game state (which are about 500-700 bytes) to a single client, the ping is around 32ms and it works smoothly, but the moment another client connects, both clients start to lag and the ping increases to 200ms and I am assuming that the problem lies with network congestion

*So my question is*, should the server automatically send data to all clients simultaneously OR should the client ask the server for an update on the game world OR is there another method I do not know about?

BTW I am using UDP protocol as I found TCP to be pretty slow after a certain amount of time in-game.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is network congestion? Have you profiled your network?

Comment: How do I profile my network?

Comment: My network code is written in Python so do I use the profile module?

Comment: That's a broad subject and better suited for other stacks. You can get started [here](http://serverfault.com/q/171488/164041); what you're looking for is whether your server is sending/recving too much data for the connection. If you use TCP you can also check whether ACK times are affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you try to send the whole game state every interval.

A better way would be to split the sync into *events* and *states*.
Events are important things like a spell that gets casted or damage that is dealt. Events need to get send over *TCP* because such packages are reliable and sequenced.
States are components like the position and rotation of entities.
States are sent over *UDP* because the sequence or packet loss does not matter here, the UDP client sends every interval.
Depending on the maximum player count you can use multicasting for the UDP client.

Example:

```
// Sent when an event was requested by a client
public struct ServerEvent
{
    public int affectedEntityId; // The entity that is affected by this event

    public int receiveDamageAmount;

    public int castedSpellId;
    public int castedSpellTargetEntityId;

    // ...
}

// Sent every interval (the Source engine uses 66.6ms)
public struct ServerState
{
    public int affectedEntityId;

    public float xPosition, yPosition;
    public float angle;

    // ...
}
```

Because you do not send the whole state of your game, you will need to identify content
in your scene. Spells and items the players collect need to be synced so that when a client
requests the casting of a spell, every other peer knows what happened.
This is easily managable with IDs. Every time new content is added to the scene a new event
gets spread over the network. Containing the resource itself and an ID you can easily address
specific entities in the game. On the server, these resources can be stored in a *dictionary*
that has a sample instance of every object.
This gives you not only a *centralized management* of ingame content and versioning, you
can also add new content to your project, without even *updating* the client application.

```
// Sent when a resource is instantiated
public struct ServerSpawn
{
    public object resourceState; // The serialized state
    public ResourceType type; // The type, identifiable with an enum
    public int resourceNetworkId;
}
```

To conclude, my approach on the problem would solve this issue by centralizing the data of your game and splitting the communication in this client/server model into *events* and *states*.

Comment: If I do this then I have to implement both TCP and UDP protocols for my network... I cant do that because I would need to rewrite my entire network code.. Plus I already tried that it just made things more complicated and buggy

Comment: BTW I just noticed I was sending packets at 60 packets per second... Is that bad?

Comment: Ok but then i cant help you. If you developed your whole network code without thinking about it...

Comment: 60 packets per seconds is way too much. The average is 15 times a second, every 66.6 miliseconds.

Comment: Ok I tried limiting sending packets to every 5 milliseconds.. Now the clients are no longer extremely laggy and the game is playable, but the game is now pretty choppy

Comment: Still not good, but ok if that solved the problem...

Comment: If I make lessen the frequency of sending packets even more, my game will become really laggy... How do I compensate for that while maintaining that frequency?

Comment: Split into events and states as said in my post.

Comment: Okay Im glad it helped. Good luck on your project.